# PhoneGap/Android, open ChildBrowser from .shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I'm packaging a mobile website (over the network) in PhoneGap and would like to intercept certain links and open them using the [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) plugin. Is it possible to trigger ChildBrowser from native code (I've already determined which links to intercept)

I've tried below code but it results in NULLPointerException:

```
ChildBrowser childBrowser = new ChildBrowser();
childBrowser.openExternal(url, true);
```

Exception Details:

```
07-29 10:49:52.632      947-947/com.abc.androidTablet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser.openExternal(ChildBrowser.java:127)
at com.mygola.androidTablet.abc_android$1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(abc_android.java:96)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:270)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:372)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is your exception? Can you post your logcat?

Comment: @caiocpricci2 added logcat

Comment: What's on line 127 on ChildBrowser.java? Which version of the plugin are you using? If you try using the code I posted below do you get an exception too?

Comment: On line 127 its 
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this.cordova.getActivity(), org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.class);

Comment: @caiocpricci2 and in your code also this.ctx is null all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end below code worked for me...

```
ChildBrowser childBrowser = new ChildBrowser();
childBrowser.cordova = this;
childBrowser.showWebPage(url, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without your logcat it's hard to give you further advice using the plugin but  if you are calling `openExternal` from the native layer there's no reason to use the plugin.  If you take a look on [the source code](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/blob/master/android-cordova-childbrowser/src/com/dhaval/mobile/plugin/ChildBrowser.java)  you'll see all it does is take your url and load it in a new `DroidGap` page.

If you take only the essential part it might help tracking down where the exception is happening.

```
function void openExternalUrl() { 

  intent = new Intent().setClass(this.ctx.getContext(), org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.class);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // This line will be removed in future.
  intent.putExtra("url", url);
  this.ctx.startActivity(intent);

 }
```

**EDIT**

You're getting a null exception on the context variable. I don't know why it's null at the time but you can easily fix that modifying the method and passing the current context. Replace `this.cordova` with context and you should be fine. Call this one from your activity pasing `this` as the last parameter `(ex: childBrowser.openExternal("http://www.google.com", true,this))`.

```
public String openExternal(String url, boolean usePhoneGap,Context context) {
   ...
  intent = new Intent().setClass(context, org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.class);
   ...
  context.startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Also to prevent errors from other calls to this function add another method with the original parameters:

```
public String openExternal(String url, boolean usePhoneGap) {
   openExternal(url,usePhoneGap,this.cordova.getActivity()); 
}
```